Sum metric values over a given time, but only if another metric is above a certain threshold
I have the following metrics:
A: homeassistant_sensor_power_w{domain="sensor", entity="sensor.sonoff_power", friendly_name="Cottage Power Power", instance="[redacted]", job="integrations/hass"}
B: homeassistant_sensor_power_w{domain="sensor", entity="sensor.sunsynk_grid_power", friendly_name="SunSynk Grid Power", instance="[redacted]", job="integrations/hass"}
I want to sum the metric values of A over a given time period, but only if B is above a certain threshold. I tried this query based on previous questions asked around the same topic, but I'm only getting 0s from the vector(0) back:
sum_over_time(homeassistant_sensor_power_w{entity="sensor.sonoff_1001691285_power"}[24h]) and ignoring(entity) (homeassistant_sensor_power_w{entity="sensor.sunsynk_grid_power"} > 20)

Basically, what I'm expecting to get back is the sum of the values from sensor.sonoff_power when sensor.sunsynk_grid_power is above 20.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Cheers!

You need to use Prometheus subqueries:
sum_over_time(
  (
    homeassistant_sensor_power_w{entity="sensor.sonoff_1001691285_power"}
      and on (instance)
    (homeassistant_sensor_power_w{entity="sensor.sunsynk_grid_power"} > 20)
  )[24h:1m]
)

Note that you need adjusting the duration after the colon in square brackets according to the interval between samples stored in Prometheus (aka scrape_interval).
Also, it looks like the homeassistant_sensor_power_w metric measures the power in Watts. If this is the case, then, I suppose, you are trying to calculate energy consumption in kWh. In this case you need multiplying the result of the query above by the scrape_interval in seconds and then dividing it by (3600*1000). For example, if the scrape_interval=1m, then the query for energy consumption in kWh will look like:
sum_over_time(
  (
    homeassistant_sensor_power_w{entity="sensor.sonoff_1001691285_power"}
      and on (instance)
    (homeassistant_sensor_power_w{entity="sensor.sunsynk_grid_power"} > 20)
  )[24h:1m]
) * 60 / (3600*1000)

